# Why won't filesync command chown on remote folder? (Solaris, share)

Tags: file, permissions, synchronization, share, solaris

I have two almost equivalent test servers with solaris 10 and Sun Directory Server. I'm trying to create an automatic method between the two to syncronize specified folders. (Those will be home and application folders.) 
So the aim is at the moment, to syncronize files on the srv1 server /export/test folder to the srv2 server /export/test folder.

What I did:

srv2: #share -o rw,root=remotesync /export/test

srv1: #filesync -a -s /export/test -d /net/192.100.55.2/export/test/ -f '*'

this copies the files from srv2/export/test to srv1/export/test, but won't keep the permissions, and give (unable to chown) error for all files.

Can somebody help me? I think it's something with the share, but I could use some experienced comment. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file system is shared from `srv2` as

```
srv2: #share -o rw,root=remotesync /export/test
```

your process does not have `root` privileges from `srv1` per the [`share` man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/share-nfs-1m.html#scrolltoc):

> root=access_list
>
> Only root users from the hosts specified in *access_list* have root access. See *access_list* below. By default, no host has root access, so
>   root users are mapped to an anonymous user ID (see the anon=uid option
>   described above). Netgroups can be used if the file system shared is
>   using UNIX authentication ( AUTH_SYS).

Read the part regarding *access_lists* carefully.

So the conditions of [`chown(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1463/chown-2.html) that cause this are:

> The operating system defines several privileges to override
>   restrictions on the chown() family of functions. When the
>   {PRIV_FILE_CHOWN} privilege is asserted in the effective set of the
>   current process, there are no restrictions except in the special
>   circumstances of changing ownership to or from uid 0. When the
>   {PRIV_FILE_CHOWN_SELF} privilege is asserted, ownership changes are
>   restricted to the files of which the ownership matches the effective
>   user ID of the current process. **If neither privilege is asserted in
>   the effective set of the calling process, ownership changes are
>   limited to changes of the group of the file to the list of
>   supplementary group IDs and the effective group ID.**

Your process does not have root access on the NFS server and almost certainly has zero extra privileges active on the file server, even if you're running as `root` on the NFS client, thus `chmod` fails with `EPERM`:

> EPERM
>
> The effective user ID does not match the owner of the file and the {PRIV_FILE_CHOWN} privilege is not asserted in the effective set of
>   the calling process, or the {PRIV_FILE_CHOWN_SELF} privilege is not
>   asserted in the effective set of the calling process.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword was "almost equivalent". I was missing the resolv.conf file on one of the machines, so the domain names were messed up when using the share command.